# Looking for ideas for efficient way to split large text file by number of lines in python

Tags: python

Iam currently trying to split the large file >200GB. Goal is to divide the large file into smaller chunks. I have written following code and it works great on smaller file. However on larger file my computer is restarting. At this point i can't figure out if it is my hardware issuse(i.e. processing power) or some other reason. Also looking for ideas if there is efficient way of doing same thing.

```
  def split(source, target, lines):
      index = 0
      block = 0
      if not os.path.exists(target):
          os.mkdir(target)
      with open(source, 'rb') as s:
          chunk = s.readlines()
          while block < len(chunk):
              with open(target+(f'file_{index:04d}.txt'), 'wb') as t:
                  t.writelines(chunk[block: block+lines])
              index+=1
              block+=lines
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the `s.readlines()` that kills it since it'll try to load it all into memory.

You could do something like

```py
with open("largeFile",'rb') as file:
    while True:
        data = file.read(1024) //blocksize
```

the `file.read()` only takes the specified blocksize, that should avoid the issue you're currently having.

EDIT:

I'm not smart, I've missed the "text file" part in your title, sorry.

In that case it should be enough to use `file.readline()` instead of `file.readlines()`